# Moving entire item rather than just indenting item

Tags: lists, margins, indentation

I'm working with a custom class file that defines a subsection environment. The subsection environment includes the following:

```
\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em}
  \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
}{
  \end{list}
```

The class file is very old, so maybe now you would use `itemize` or `enumerate` instead of list.

When I add items to the list, they are all on the same level. I want to make some of the bullets sub-bullets relative to other bullets. Obviously in MS Word you would just tab. However, I'm not sure how to do that here. I tried the following:

```
\setlength{\itemindent}{0.25in}
```

However, this only indents, so if the item is more than a single line, the text is not lined up under the bullet. It overshoots to the left.

I need something that will allow me to move the entire item rather than just indent the first line. What would allow me to do this? I tried using `\itemize` to make a nested list but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be wise to use the standard list environments, since it would allow you to branch out using packages that provide a more stable way of managing lists and they way they could be nested.

Here's an option to add an `\indentlist{<len>}` parameter to your lists. Similar to a `\begin{list}`...`\end{list}` approach, you'd use `\indentlist{<len>}` to indent the remaining part of the list by `<len>`. If you want to revert back to the previous list indents, use `\indentlist{-<len>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indentlist}[1]{%
  \par% Force new paragraph
  \addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{#1}% Indent entire list
  \addtolength{\linewidth}{-#1}% Reduce line width by indent
  \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{
  \leftmargin=0em
  \itemsep=-0.5em
  \vspace{-0.5em}
}
  \item First item
  
  \item \lipsum*[1][1-2]
  
  \indentlist{0.25in}

    \item Third item
    
    \item \lipsum*[1][1-2]

    \indentlist{0.25in}

      \item Fifth item
    
      \item \lipsum*[1][1-2]
      
    \indentlist{-0.25in}
  
    \item Seventh item
  
  \indentlist{-0.25in}
  
  \item Eighth item
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to work but an oddity is that `\indentlist{0.25in}` applies to both the line directly above and following in my document. So, if I have 5 items and want every item after the first to be a sub-bullet, I need to put `\indentlist{0.25in}` in between the second and third items. That's easy to do, but it seems odd that `\indentlist{0.25in}` is grabbing the line above.

Comment: @Pond892: That's because you're condensing your code and removing the vertical separation (blank lines) I've added to my example. I've updated `\indentlist` to insert a `\par` which would be similar. This should fix your issue.

Comment: @Warner: That works, thanks!