# Matching bullet list spacing outside list

Tags: spacing, bullets

I'm using a class file with the following:

```
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em}
  \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
}{
  \end{list}
```

This allows me to create bulleted lists. @Werner showed me how to use `\indentlist{0.25in}` to create nested lists (see [Moving entire item rather than just indenting item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580116/moving-entire-item-rather-than-just-indenting-item)).

Another part of my document uses the following format:

```
    Text \hfill Date \\ 
    Text \\
    $\cdot$ Text \\
```

I want to make the spacing before and after the `$\cdot$` bullet directly above match the spacing in the lists elsewhere in the document. This seems to work:

```
 \hspace*{length}$\cdot$\hspace{length} Text \\
```

However, I'm not sure what lengths the other lists are using. Since I used `\indentlist{0.25in}`, perhaps `\hspace*{0.25in}` is correct for the space before the bullet. The list instructions posted above are given inside a subsection environment and the section environment has `\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}`. Moving on to the space after the bullet, I'm not sure what length the lists are using. Perhaps it's a default length, but I'm not sure what the default would be. So, I'm wondering what lengths I should use for the two spaces to match the rest of the document. Perhaps there is a better approach I should use?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that item labels in a list is typically set `r`ight-aligned; here's a visual of a typical list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{itemize}
  \item Zeroth
  \item[1] First
  \item[11] Second
  \item[111] Third
  \item[1111] Fourth
  \item[11111] Fifth
  \item[111111] Sixth
  \item[1111111] Seventh
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Your list is similar; you only set the `leftmargin` to be `0pt`. That sets the list flush with the left margin and the label inside the margin. So you can do the following to replicate it for a non-`list` item:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indentlist}[1]{%
  \par% Force new paragraph
  \addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{#1}% Indent entire list
  \addtolength{\linewidth}{-#1}% Reduce line width by indent
  \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\fakeitem}[1][0pt]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hspace*{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{$\cdot$}%
    \hspace{\labelsep}%
  }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{
  \leftmargin=0em
  \itemsep=-0.5em
}
  \item First
  \indentlist{1em}
    \item Second
\end{list}

\fakeitem First

\fakeitem[1em] Second

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is too much space between the lines. I take it ```\itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}``` or just ```\itemsep -0.5em``` is controlling this in the list but how do I apply that here?

Comment: @Pond892: Your `\vspace{-0.5em}` would be similar to reducing the usual `topsep` measurement of [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) as it is executed at the top of the list, while `\itemsep` is applied as between `\item`s to `sep`erate them vertically. If you want the items closer together, you can probably add a `\vspace{-0.5em}` immediately after `\par` in the `\newcommand` definition of `\fakeitem`.